# how can I use gpucoder.stencilKernel function for a 3D image (colored image) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gpu, block

I have to divide each image to separate blocks and then apply a function on each block in Matlab. In CPU, I used blokproc function for block processing of image. But it takes too time. So I have to use GPU. But GPU does not recognize blokproc function, So I have to use another function. There is gpucoder.stencilKernel function but it only works for 2D image(gray scaled images). My images are 3D (colored image in 3 channels R,G and B).
Is there another function for block processing on GPU?

I searched many times, but I could not find any function for block processing of colored images on GPU.

Comment: Can you not use the 2D version for each channel? or you need the channels mixed? Or just write your block-separating code first, then accelerate the function with inbuilt MATLAB GPU functions instead of relying in blockproc

Comment: No, I can not. I have to use channels mixed.